# How to have conditional group by in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with this columns:

```
tblTransaction 
(
    Transaction_ID, 
    Transaction_RequestTransactionCode,
    Transaction_MobileErrorCode
)
```

I want to have the count of EVERY transactions, that it's MobileErrorCode is 0.

so my query is like this:

```
SELECT        Transaction_RequestTransactionCode, COUNT(Transaction_ID) AS _Count
FROM          tblTransaction
WHERE        (Transaction_MobileErrorCode = '0')
GROUP BY Transaction_RequestTransactionCode
```

the result is this:

[image]

It dosent have any error, but its not my result. when one transaction code dose have the condition (Transaction_MobileErrorCode = '0'), it dosent appear in result with _Count = 0.

I mean this result, with last raw:

[image]

Comment: If it's a SQLServer question, please add the "sql-server" tag to your question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform a conditional aggregate move the condition from `where` clause to `Count` using `case` statement aggregate

```
SELECT Transaction_RequestTransactionCode,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Transaction_MobileErrorCode = '0' THEN Transaction_ID
             END) AS _Count
FROM   tblTransaction
GROUP  BY Transaction_RequestTransactionCode
```

Comment: Count can't use a conditon. it counts all that is not `null`, no matter if `0` or `1`

Comment: @juergend - really!! thats not true check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288058/conditional-count-on-a-field

Comment: I just checked that. You're right. So am I :) You can use a condition but you must make sure that the `false` part is `null`

Comment: @juergend Since we are not using `else` part is `case` statement all the other values will be `NULL` and those won't be counted

Answer (score 2):

Use `sum` to sum up the condition you want to count

```
SELECT        Transaction_RequestTransactionCode, 
              SUM(case when Transaction_MobileErrorCode = '0' then 1 else 0 end) AS _Count
FROM          tblTransaction
GROUP BY Transaction_RequestTransactionCode
```