# Column count based on a condition

Tags: oracle, count

I have created an oracle query like as shown below,the query is working fine
but the problem is that I want one more column which is the count of name where category should be A and id should be 1

```
SELECT name, velocity, COUNT(*) AS count, category FROM section GROUP BY name, velocity
```

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Count on a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288058/conditional-count-on-a-field)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
SELECT name, velocity, COUNT(*) AS count, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'A' AND id = 1 THEN 1 END)
FROM section 
GROUP BY name, velocity
```

This should work.

If record does not meet the condition then it will return a NULL, and count skips NULL fields.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
SELECT name, velocity, COUNT(*) AS count, 
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'A' AND id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM section 
GROUP BY name, velocity
```

Comment: You forgot the id condition

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, velocity, COUNT(*) AS count, category, 
       (select count(distinct name) from section where category = 'A' and id = 1)
FROM section 
GROUP BY name, velocity
```