# Questions on SQL count and Valuable Definition

Tags: sql, database

May I ask how to count the broken door in below table?
I want to show the record of Block B also, but I only can show Block A record.

Also, if my selection table query is too long, but I will reuse many times.
How can I define the valuable to the long selection query?

Table: doorStatus

| Door | Block | key_Number | Broken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| door1 | A | 001 | Y |
| door2 | A | 001 | Y |
| door3 | A | 002 | Y |
| door4 | B | 013 | N |

Except result:

| Block | key_number | Count_Broken |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 001 | 2 |
| A | 002 | 1 |
| B | 013 | 0 |

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note: Removed the tags "oracle" and "mysql". If you use a specific DB, tag this DB type only. In this case, the syntax of the required query will very likely not differ between different DB's.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column count based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169707/column-count-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it: group by block and key_number, count the number of broken.

```
-- prep data
create table door_status (
    door        varchar(10),
    block       char(1),
    key_number  varchar(3),
    broken      char(1));
    
insert into door_status
values
('door1','A','001','Y'),
('door2','A','001','Y'),
('door3','A','002','Y'),
('door4','B','013','N');

-- query
select block,
       key_number,
       sum(case broken when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as count_broken
  from door_status
 group by 1,2;
```

Result:

```
block|key_number|count_broken|
-----+----------+------------+
A    |001       |           2|
A    |002       |           1|
B    |013       |           0|
```

Comment: I'd recommend `GROUP BY block, key_number`, since it's standard SQL and portable. Especially since the dbms is unknown.

Comment: I agree, using column names when grouping is generally recommended to keep queries as most clear as possible. Due to the same reason, I would prefer to use COUNT instead of SUM because the entries should be counted, not sumed. Of course, SUM will also work correctly in this case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a `GROUP BY` clause on both block and key_number with a `CASE` on broken's value. `COUNT` the "Y" entries only:

```
SELECT block, key_number, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN broken = 'Y' THEN 1 END) AS Count_Broken
FROM doorStatus
GROUP BY block, key_number;
```

Will produce this outcome based on your sample data:

| Block | key_number | Count_Broken |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 001 | 2 |
| A | 002 | 1 |
| B | 013 | 0 |

See here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dkmis9ZV)