# how can i run a sql query that can count rows and set them as different variables depending on the value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a variable that counts the number of occurrences in a row and sets them as a variable, depending on the particular value of 'action_type'

```
SELECT COUNT(v.visits_id) visits,s.source_type source,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.action_type=2) sale,COUNT(CASE WHEN a.action_type=1) contact FROM visits v 
    JOIN sources s ON v.source_id=s.source_id 
    JOIN actions a ON a.source_id=s.source_id
    GROUP BY source ORDER BY visits DESC
```

So in this scenario I would want to be creating two variables for each row called sale and contact, which would have counted the occurrences when action_type=1 or action_type=2

How is this achieved?

Comment: Do you mean **column**? I can't see any variables created.

Comment: yes sorry of course

Comment: Okay, what you need is conditional count (that's the term I used to search). I will have to flag this as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Count on a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288058/conditional-count-on-a-field)