# SQL - Counting with Where

Tags: sql, counting

I have a very simple SQL question. I have a database table with the following columns:

1. Part Number
2. Sales Type (for simplicity, call it Sales Type 1,2,3,4,5)

I am hoping to write a query that gives the following three columns:

- The part number
- The total number of sales for Sales Type = 2
- The total number of sales for Sales Type <> 2

I can easily get two of the three columns to display with code similar to the code below but I'm stumped on how to get all three to show up at the same time.

```
SELECT 
    PartNumber AS PartNumber,
    COUNT(*) AS SalesCount
FROM 
    SalesTable
WHERE 
    SalesType = 2
GROUP BY 
    I.PartNumber
```

I'm guessing this may be very easy - I'm a SQL noob and this is my first post!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no `and` in select statement. So had you tested your query?

Comment: You are missing GROUP BY.

Comment: Just edited it should be "AS". I simplified the example for this question so I couldn't test my code exactly. Do you know how to display all three columns as I'm hoping for?

Comment: If I had GROUP BY it will not be three columns though right?

Comment: The COUNT doesn't work without GROUP BY (except under MySQL where it also doesn't work, but you don't see it as explicitly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you want something like this:

```
 SELECT PartNumber, sum(case when SalesType=2 then 1 else 0) as Type2SalesCount,
    sum(case when SalesType<>2 then 1 else 0) as NoNType2SalesCount
    FROM SalesTable
    Group by PartNumber
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks!!! This did it (I did have to add an END ... else 0 END). But this was exactly what I was looking for --- thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a [conditional count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288058/conditional-count-on-a-field)

```
SELECT 
    PartNumber, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN SalesType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SaleTypeTwoCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SalesType <> 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SalesOtherCount
FROM 
    SalesTable
GROUP BY
    PartNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't actually run it, but something like this should work...

```
SELECT
    PartNumber,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SalesType = 2 THEN 1 END) Count2,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN SalesType <> 2 THEN 1 END) CountNot2
FROM
   SalesTable
GROUP BY
   PartNumber;
```

Note that COUNT(expression) only counts non-NULLs, while COUNT(*) counts all rows.

The...

```
CASE WHEN SalesType = 2 THEN 1 END
```

...is equivalent to...

```
CASE WHEN SalesType = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
```

...and will result in NULL when SalesType <> 2, which is not counted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case for example:
`saletype= case when saletype == 2 then count(saletype)
when saletype <> 2 then count(saletype)`