# SQL Server : different aggregate functions conditional on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this (significantly simplified):

```
|student_id|Courses| grades |
+----------+-------+--------+
|    001   |  Math |   95   |
|    001   |  Math |   83   |
|    001   | Others|   33   |
|    002   |  Math |   92   |
|    002   | Others|   12   |
|    002   | Others|   72   |
```

What I want:

1. Count of 'Math'
2. Minimum of 'Others'
3. Grouped by student_id

Desired outcome:

```
|student_id|Num_math|min_others|
+----------+--------+----------+
|    001   |    2   |    33    |
|    002   |    1   |    12    |
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`, `CASE`.

Comment: Or, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288058/conditional-count-on-a-field) but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY student_id` and conditional `SUM` and `MIN`:

```
   SELECT 
    student_id, 
    SUM(CASE Courses WHEN 'Math' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  Num_math,
    MIN(CASE Courses WHEN 'Others' THEN grades ELSE NULL END) AS min_others
   FROM tablename
    GROUP BY student_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Gordon said, you need to use `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`, `CASE` AND `MIN`. This is what you want:

```
SELECT student_id
        ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Courses='Math' THEN grades ELSE NULL END) Math
        ,MIN(CASE WHEN Courses='Others' THEN grades ELSE NULL END) Others
FROM Student
GROUP BY student_id
```

Comment: That first one has to be `sum`.  0 is still a value and will be counted by `count`.

Comment: you are right, sum or count with null can work. I have updated. thanks for double check.